# MYSQL SELECT results HAVING Balance from Sum of two tables two columns

Tags: sql, mysql, join, sum, coalesce

I have 3 Database tables Named Order_summary, Invoices, Payments

Order_summary

| id | order_ref | Customer_ref |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10055 | 15 |
| 2 | 10056 | 24 |
| 3 | 10057 | 26 |

Invoices

| id | order_ref | Item | rate | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10055 | Test Item | 100.00 | 2.00 |
| 2 | 10055 | Test Item | 50.00 | 1.00 |
| 3 | 10055 | Test Item | 200.00 | 1.00 |
| 4 | 10055 | Test Item | 65.00 | 3.00 |
| 5 | 10056 | Test Item | 10.00 | 10.00 |
| 6 | 10056 | Test Item | 1065.00 | 2.00 |
| 7 | 10057 | Test Item | 560.00 | 6.00 |
| 8 | 10057 | Test Item | 15.00 | 1.00 |
| 9 | 10057 | Test Item | 652.00 | 2.00 |
| 10 | 10057 | Test Item | 125.00 | 1.00 |

Payments

| id | order_ref | Amount | referance | method |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10055 | 50.00 | sds56s | cash |
| 2 | 10055 | 100.00 | 21sdas | card |
| 3 | 10056 | 1165.00 | 54asdf | cash |
| 4 | 10055 | 150.00 | asd5a | cash |
| 5 | 10057 | 5000.00 | sd6fa | cash |

Table contents here are not real numbers. Stucture is like this.

I want to JOIN reulsts to  Order_summary table which are grater than Zero when SUM(Invoices.rate*qty) - (subtract) SUM(Payments.amount).

Simply I want to filter the invoices which are not fully paid.

**order_ref** column in Order_summary is unique. No multiple.
**order_ref** column in Invoice has multiple.
**order_ref** column in Payments has multiple.

Results should be  like below.

| id | order_ref | invoice_total | Payment_total | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10055 | 645.00 | 300.00 | 345.00 |
| 2 | 10056 | 2230.00 | 1165.00 | 1065.00 |
| 3* | 10057 | 4804.00 | 5000.00 | -196.00 |

- This last result line should not be in the results. Because balance is less than Zero. (Invoice paid).

Can anyone Please help me with this. I have tried several LEFT JOINs and COALESE, But I have not successed.

```
SELECT os.*,
       COALESCE(SUM(i.rate * i.qty), 0) AS invoice_total,
       COALESCE(SUM(p.amount), 0) AS payment_total,
       COALESCE(SUM(i.rate * i.qty), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(p.amount), 0) AS balance
FROM Order_summary os
LEFT JOIN invoices i ON i.order_ref = os.order_ref
LEFT JOIN Payments p ON p.order_ref = os.order_ref
GROUP BY os.order_ref
```

Tried this and SUM(Payment.amount) and SUM(Invoices.rate*Invoices.qty) columns show very large value which is not correct.

Comment: Try aggregating in subqueries before joining.

Comment: *SUM(Payment.amount) and SUM(Invoices.rate*Invoices.qty) columns show very large value which is not correct.* Common JOIN multiplying. See the comment provided above.

Comment: Finaly I have managed to find the solution. Below code works.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works. Finaly I have found th solution.

```
SELECT Order_summary.order_ref, Customers.displayName, PaymentSum.SumOfPaymentAmount, InvoiceItemSum.SumOfAmount, SUM(InvoiceItemSum.SumOfAmount-PaymentSum.SumOfPaymentAmount) AS balance
FROM Order_summary
INNER JOIN Customers
  ON Customers.id = Order_summary.customer_ref
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT order_ref, SUM((rate-lineDisc)*qty) AS SumOfAmount
    FROM invoices
    GROUP BY invoices.order_ref) InvoiceItemSum
  ON InvoiceItemSum.order_ref = Order_summary.order_ref
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT order_ref, SUM(amount) AS SumOfPaymentAmount
    FROM Payments
    GROUP BY Payments.order_ref) PaymentSum
  ON PaymentSum.order_ref = Order_summary.order_ref
GROUP BY Order_summary.order_ref
HAVING balance <= 0
```